# Approach to Python package contents that are both part of the 'public interface' and 'used internally'?

Tags: python

I am in the midst of refactoring some single-file Python modules into multi-file packages and I am encountering the same problem pattern repeatedly: I have objects that are part of the **public interface** of the package, but must also be **used internally** by submodules the package.

```
mypackage/
    __init__.py  # <--- Contains object 'cssURL'
    views.py     # <--- Needs to use object 'cssURL'
```

In this case, it's important that clients of `mypackage` have access to `mypackage.cssURL`.  However, my submodule, `views.py`, also needs it, but has no access to the contents of `__init__.py`.  Sure, I can create another submodule like so:

```
mypackage/
    __init__.py
    views.py
    style.py     # <--- New home for 'cssURL'
```

However, if I did this every time, it seems like it would multiply the number of submodules exceedingly.  Moreover, clients must now refer to `mypackage.cssURL` as `mypackage.style.cssURL`, or else I must create a synonym in `__init__.py` like this:

```
import style
cssURL = style.cssURL
```

I think I am doing something wrong.  Is there a better way to handle these kinds of package members that are both part of the **public interface** and **used internally**?

Comment: Or put `from style import cssURL` in `__init__.py`... Where is `cssURL` currently, just defined in `__init__.py` itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would structure it as follows:

```
/mypackage
    __init__.py
       from style import cssURL
       ...
    style.py
       cssURL = '...'  # or whatever
       ...
    views.py
       from .style import cssURL
       ...
```

If other modules within the same package need them, I wouldn't define names in `__init__.py`; just create an alias there for external consumers to use.

Comment: I am encouraged by the unanimity here.  I wonder what effect this strategy has on documentation generated from pydoc?  (I will see.)

Comment: @DavidCharles any docstrings are brought through by `import`, so I wouldn't expect any issues.

Comment: Yes, `cssURL` appears in the pydoc-generated HTML for `mypackage`.  Thank you!

Comment: Yes, `cssURL` is rendered by pydoc, however it does not render the docstring because `cssURL` is an ordinary string.  (All these things go into the 'Data' section.)  So, I decided to publicize with a function by the same name.

Comment: @DavidCharles strings can't have docstrings, so I don't think that would have made a difference

Comment: yes, that is my point.  Strings cannot have docstrings, but functions can, so I created a function, `def cssURL(): return _style.cssURL` and put the docstring on the function.

Comment: Oh dear. Adding `from .submodule import SomeClass` to `__init__.py` does not get `SomeClass` into the pydocs for the package.  :(

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to the current package as `.`:

```
# views.py
from . import cssURL
```

See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the preferred way is to create a "synonym" in `__init__.py` with "`from .style import cssURL`"; cf. [the source for the `json` module](https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson/blob/master/simplejson/__init__.py#L112).